# How do I check if an element exists in a queue ( LinkedList ) before adding it?

Tags: java, queue

How do I check if an element exists in a queue  ( LinkedList ) before adding it ?

EX:
Address [id=1, url=https://www.google.com, size=2, queue=[request [requestId=1], request [requestId=2]]]

I can't add queue=[request [requestId=1], request [requestId=1]] because they have the same requestId.

Comment: Using the contains method

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a `LinkedHashMap` instead, if you need to perform the check very often and the queue can be large.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`contains(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method

contains description:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
> formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
> element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).
> [...]
>
> Parameters: o –
> element whose presence in this list is to be tested
>
> Returns: true if
> this list contains the specified element

Answer (score 0):

[`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html) implements the [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) interface, which defines the [`Collection#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method.

You can do what you're after with any class that derives from `Collection` easily by just using the `contains` method.

See the docs on [`LinkedList#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) for more information.

Note: It uses [`Objects#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#equals(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) to determine if the item is in the `Collection`.

If you have the same reference, I think you'll be good. If you have different references representing the same data, then you may need to [`@Override`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Override.html) the [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method on your object.

Answer (score -1):

Below code may help you...

```
package com.example.Solution;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class Sol {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Queue<Address> q1= new LinkedList<>();
        q1.add(new Address("abc",1,"url1"));
        Address a1=new Address("abc",1,"url");
        if(!q1.contains(a1))
            q1.add(a1);
        Address a2=new Address("abc",2,"url");
        if(!q1.contains(a2)){
            q1.add(a2);
        }
        Address a3=new Address("abc",1,"url2");
        if(!q1.contains(a3)){
            q1.add(a3);
        }
        System.out.println(q1.size());
    }
}
class Address {
    String name;
    int id;
    String url;

    public Address(String name, int id, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o1){
        Address address=(Address) o1;
        return address.getId()==this.id;
    }
}
```